# jar file not connecting to the database

Tags: database, database-connection, derby

i created a java project long back which requires connection to derby which is an inbuilt netbeans database. i always used to open netbeans, compile the files and run and it used to work just fine. then i learnt how to make a jar file out of it on netbeans and i did it.now when i run the jar file it does not connect to the database.when i login it just gets stuck up cause apparently is not connecting to db. could anyone plz help me out? Thanking you in advance.

P.S. Please be very simple in your explanation. I am good with coding but not in understanding a lot of programming jargon. try to explain me like a u would explain a layman if possible.

Comment: Please show us the line of code which contains the JDBC Connection URL. This will typically be a call to DriverManager.getConnection(), and there will be a string which begins 'jdbc:'. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html for some simple explanations of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
 con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Ayush","ayush","12345");
 st=con.createStatement();
 rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from AYUSH.INFO");                //from what i know i have made the connections right bt the problem is that unless i manually Go to Services in Netbeans and Connect to the database, it wont work. so i actually need to know how to start up the database on its own when it sees a connection being attempted to it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the ClientDriver, which means your Java program is attempting to connect to the Derby Network Server running on your same machine ("localhost") at port 1527.

If that connection is not working, the simplest explanation is that the Derby Network Server is not running at the moment that you run your Java program.

The commands you are running in Netbeans ("Go To Services in Netbeans and Connect") may be automatically starting a Derby Network Server for you.

You can start a Derby Network Server on your own. It's just another Java program; the Derby binary distribution contains some scripts that you can run to start it. Go here to read about how to start up the Derby Network Server and configure it so that it knows where your Ayush database is: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/getstart/twwdactivity4.html and also: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/adminguide/cadminconfig86869.html#cadminconfig86869