# Unable to connect to Apache Derby database

Tags: java, derby

I try to use `Apache Derby 10.15.2.0` to write a table and to read from it. I run database on local Windows machine, installed Java version: `14.0.2`

Output of `java -jar %DERBY_HOME%\lib\derbyrun.jar ij` command:

> ij version 10.15

I use following Java code to establish a connection, create a database and a table after that:

```
Connection connect = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;

try {
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    connect = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testdb;create=true");
    PreparedStatement createTable = connect.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE Student (\n" +
            "   Id INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,\n" +
            "   Age INT NOT NULL,\n" +
            "   First_Name VARCHAR(255),\n" +
            "   last_name VARCHAR(255),\n" +
            "   PRIMARY KEY (Id)\n" +
            ");");

    statement = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * from Student");

    resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        String user = resultSet.getString("First_Name");
        String number = resultSet.getString("Id");
        System.out.println("User: " + user);
        System.out.println("ID: " + number);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

Error message during execution:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException Connection refused: connect

Comment: did you start the derby?

Comment: You have to start the Derby Network Server. See this answer for more background: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24377769/193453